# How can count all item of query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Structure of data:

- `Table1`: ITEM_SPEC_ID, NAME, PRIMARY KEY (ITEM_SPEC_ID)
- `Table2`: ITEM_SPEC_ID, TOOL_ID, PRIMARY KEY (ITEM_SPEC_ID, TOOL_ID)

I want get `ITEM_SPEC_ID, TOOL_ID` and count total number of `TOOL_ID`

This is my query, but it doesn't return the correct result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT   
    a.ITEM_SPEC_ID, b.TOOL_ID, COUNT(b.TOOL_ID) AS num_tool_id 
FROM   
    Table1 a  
JOIN 
    Table2 b ON a.ITEM_SPEC_ID = b.ITEM_SPEC_ID 
GROUP BY 
    a.ITEM_SPEC_ID, b.TOOL_ID
```

Expected result: `num_tool_id = 1`

[image]

Expected output: I want value of column `num_tool_id = 2` in above case.

[image]

How can I count all items of query?

Comment: Because you group by ITEM_SPEC_ID where all item_spec_id is unique. Please add a table for expected output

Comment: expected output: above image with num_tool_id =2

Comment: Please add a table for it. And also show us the result of the query even though it is not the desired output

Comment: The group by can change?

Comment: It is not really possible to give an appropriate answer without the details asked by @learning

Comment: Also, you want to count occurrences of each tool_id OR the total of the unique tool_id? @DT

Comment: I want get ITEM_SPEC_ID, TOOL_ID and count total number TOOL_ID of result.

Comment: Please edit the question, add a table for your desired output. Thank you!

Comment: Provide DDL and DML commands as well pls

Comment: @DT, why are you grouping by those columns?
Is ITEM_SPEC_ID a primary key?
what kind of relation do the tables have? is it one to many or one to one?
You need to provide this details for us to be able to provide an accurate and detailed answer. Else, people will start to downvote your question because of incompleteness

Comment: i updated "Struct of Data" in my question

Comment: why adding an expected output table is such difficult?

Comment: hi:) i added expected output table

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info
Section `How to ask good questions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you share enough information to us. Else, it's hard for us to help! Adding a table for e

You can do in this way if you want to get the number of unique tool_id

Check out this [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jVNfPMFhxQhzE3EVxdXaxs/0)

```
SELECT a.item_spec_id, a.tool_id,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(tool_id)) as tot_num FROM items) as tot_num
FROM items a
```

Comment: Thank you, it is ok. but must edit to join 2 table.

Comment: JOINING a table should not be that difficult. You can add this in by your own.